# domain redirect to STRATO.NL managed server (block?)

Tags: domain, redirect, block

I have a managed server from strato.nl I have a domain on OVH and I want for my OVH domain to redirect to the managed server.

I have configured the DNS so that xxx.ovh domains points to the IP of the managed server 85.214.xxx.xxx,  after the redirect propagates I only get the following error message

> Fehler - Aufgerufene Domain nicht gefunden.Die gesuchte Seite wurde nicht gefunden!
>   Die Domain ist noch nicht vollständig konfiguriert, bitte versuchen Sie es zu einem späteren Zeitpunkt nochmals.

(the domain was not found and the domain is not completely configure, come back alter)

I have asked strato help and they said I can point my xxx.ovh domain to the server, I have done this with dedicated server and VPS but this is the first time I do it with a managed server.

I think that if the managed server doesn't have the domain it will give this error, and block external redirect. Has anyone experienced this ???? Any tips ??? I am missing something ????  Can't find extra info on the topic !!!

Thanks 
J.

Comment: What kind of managed server are we talking about? Did you set the host entries correctly for your server? If it is a webserver, did you set the hostname in the webservers configuration? Did you configure a firewall? If so, did you open the ports for your desired service? Where did you get the error message? More info please.

Comment: We are talking about strato managed server / managed hosting, the company strato manages the firewall, webserver configuration, I can just do a .htacess file, set domain and sub domain configuration. I have limited FTP access and a control panel.

Comment: Ok, so we're talking about a webserver. When did you change the DNS entry? If you can reach your managed server through your IP address and your DNS is configured correcetly this is most likely just a matter of time. DNS entries need some time to propagate through the internet since DNS-Servers keep caches with varying TTL. Try again in a few hours.

Comment: DNS entry was changed on the control panel on OVH something like isric.ovh --> 85.214.253.67 (type A) When I do a dig command from the prompt. I get the correct IP. Also I  was wondering if I could  write a ServerAlias  with isric.ovh on  a .htaccess  but this is not possible . I think that the managed server only accepts domains that was configure with. I personally dislike STRATO, the customer service is bad and there no serious technical information  (documentation is just: click here and there) and all error are reported in German.